# Things We Can Do With Html5 And Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, sencha-touch

i am new to phonegap and html5 appplication development,i am starting to learn html5 for developing phonegap application from here http://www.w3.org/html/logo/ i cam to know that what can we do with html5,but still there are some confusion in my mind.my question may be generall but i want to know that why we are using html5 with phonegap?and what can we do with html5 for mobile application development?if any one have good link or guide about this than it will be pleasure to mee,if any one have knowledge regarding this than tell me.
Thanks in Advance
Aamirkhan I.

Comment: See http://phonegap.com/about/ for an explanation of the platform and its rationale.

Comment: well thanks for reply i really was not expecting such bad response to this question i wanted to know some thing from here and diapointed.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Phonegap you have access to a great number of mobile capabilites, like camera, accelerometer, and almost all other. But you should take care when using HTML5 features, because they may not be compatible with all mobile systems, as Phonegap uses the native browser inside a native app (an Android Phonegap App will use the native Android browser, for example). But it's completelly possible to create almost any app not relying on exclusive HTML5 features

I'm using it to create *simple** apps, like trivia games, form based apps, etc. I'm loving it, as I'm already a web developer just using my HTML/CSS/JS skills for mobile.

[Here](http://phonegap.com/apps/) you can see a lot of real world projects.

<sub>What I mean with "simple" is that I'd **not** recommend Phonegap to create a fast paced game with lots of elements moving (using canvas, JavaScript or whatever). For that I would recommend Adobe Air(Flash) or native Java.</sub>

Comment: can we create dynamic view using PhoneGap? means we are getting HTML5 as response from server?